# Android - Snackbar - Crashing with FATAL Exception after Show() is called

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-snackbar

I have following code for displaying Snackbar in my App.

```
#region Snackbar

        private const int SnackbarDuration = 1100;

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows a snackbar. Counts with the fact that there is a CoordinatorLayout with ID coordinatorLayout in your activity layout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="activity"></param>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        /// <param name="duration"></param>
        public static void ShowSnackbar(Activity activity, string text, int duration = SnackbarDuration)
        {
            StyleAndShowSnackbar(activity, text, duration);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows a snackbar. Counts with the fact that there is a CoordinatorLayout with ID coordinatorLayout in your activity layout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="activity"></param>
        /// <param name="stringId"></param>
        /// <param name="duration"></param>
        public static void ShowSnackbar(Activity activity, int stringId, int duration = SnackbarDuration)
        {
            StyleAndShowSnackbar(activity, stringId, duration);
        }

        private static void StyleAndShowSnackbar(Activity activity, object stringOrStringId, int duration)
        {
            var snackbarLayout = activity.FindViewById<CoordinatorLayout>(Resource.Id.coordinatorLayout);
            if (snackbarLayout == null) return;

            Snackbar snackbar;
            if (stringOrStringId is int)
                snackbar = Snackbar.Make(snackbarLayout, (int)stringOrStringId, duration);
            else
                snackbar = Snackbar.Make(snackbarLayout, (string)stringOrStringId, duration);

            snackbar.StyleSnackbar();
            snackbar.Show();
            snackbar.Dispose();
            snackbarLayout.Dispose();
        }

        private static void StyleSnackbar(this Snackbar snackbar)
        {
            var snackbarView = (ViewGroup)snackbar.View;
            snackbarView.SetBackgroundColor(Color.LightGray);
            var snackbarTextView = snackbarView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.snackbar_text);
            snackbarTextView.SetTextColor(Color.Black);

            snackbarView.Dispose();
            snackbarTextView.Dispose();
        }

        #endregion
```

This is the coordinator layout that is being referenced from my code (note that this is included in my layouts - it is not being used on its own):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything worked well on API 22 until I test it on Android M and earlier than API 22(might not be the main cause). after Show() is called the App crashes with following exception.

> 01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482): Process:
>   com.psonar.android, PID: 2482 01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime(
>   2482): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'int android.text.Layout.getLineCount()' on a null object
>   reference 01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$SnackbarLayout.onMeasure(Snackbar.java:707)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLay01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:18788) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 01-01
>   15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 01-01 15:10:45.454
>   E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   01-01 15:10:45.454 E/AndroidRuntime( 2482):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I tried removing Dispose() calls from my code to see if that would have have an effect but it does not.

Comment: `NullPointerException` at `android.text.Layout.getLineCount()`. Are you sure that there's any string to display on SnackBar? Try to catch it by `Log`

Comment: post the code where you are suing the method getLineCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple cleaning the solution and completely uninstalling the app and reinstalling did the trick.

I wish it was something more but at first it worked then it stopped then cleaning and reinstalling resolved it (for Android M I had to delete and reinstall the device image).

Comment: so just clean will fix it how come ??!!

Comment: I face many issue in Xamarin , they really need to do something , I waste 40% of my time try to build and deploy in my device

Comment: @MinaFawzy I actually get this problem now everytime I update nuget package related to the Snackbar. But then I just go, delete my bin, obj folders, restart VS and I am up and running again :)